# Setting dependencies between mapped Airflow tasks

Tags: airflow

Given a dag using Airflow's dynamic task mapping feature, e.g.:

```py
@dag(start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 1), schedule=None)
def my_dag:
  @task
  def find_ids:
    return [1, 2, 3, 4] # pretend it's an API response

  op = SomeOperator.partial(…).expand(id=find_ids)

  find_ids >> op

my_dag()
```

This will schedule 4 operators to run in parallel, one with each id in the list returned by `find_ids`.

But instead of running all 4 in parallel I want

- the operator with id=2 to be dependent on the operator with id=1, and
- the operator with id=4 to be dependent on the operator with id=3

I can't find any way to achieve this in the Airflow docs. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: There is no such functionality. If you'd like a depth-first execution you must separate expand calls using task groups objects. see docs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#depth-first-execution
This is a design choice. Feel free to raise your thoughts on https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/25032